# Cómo obtiene printf() en C los valores mostrados por cada especificador de formato

Tags: c, printf, parámetros

Tengo una duda sobre cómo obtiene los datos, para cada especificador `%`, la función `printf()`. Creo suponer que, por cada especificador, obtiene los valores de la pila donde se introdujeron las variables pasadas por argumentos. Como `printf()` tiene una lista variable de argumentos, dentro de la función no hay manera de saber cuántos argumentos y de qué tipo han sido pasados. Por lo tanto, es la información detallada por los especificadores la usada para ir obteniendo correctamente los valores de los argumentos pasados.

Mi duda viene por lo siguiente: creo suponer que por cada especificador indicado se obtiene un valor de la pila del tamaño precisado por el especificador (`%d` para `int`, `%ld` para `long`, `%lld` para `long long`, etc). Por lo tanto, si dentro de `printf()` hay dos especificadores `%d` y `%lld`, primero obtendrá un valor `int` de la pila y a continuación obtendrá un valor `long long` de la pila que contiene los valores de los argumentos pasados.

Explicado lo anterior, si miramos el siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int ui = 0;
    unsigned long long ulli = ULLONG_MAX;

    printf("TAMAÑOS\nint:%8zu\nlong long: %zu\n", 
           sizeof(int), sizeof(long long));

    printf("\nulli: %u\nui:   %llu\nulli: %u", ulli, ui, ulli);

    return 0;
}
```

Con la siguiente salida:

```
TAMAÑOS 
int:       4 
long long: 8

ulli: 4294967295 
ui:   0 
ulli: 4294967295
```

Podemos ver que, al imprimir el segundo valor correspondiente a la variable `ui` usando el especificador `%llu`, el valor mostrado es `0` pero, aunque el valor de la variable `ui` sea `0` y parezca que lo hace correctamente, ¿por qué muestra su valor?

**¿No tendría que haber impreso un segundo valor `unsigned long long` de la pila, después de obtener un primer valor `unsigned int` para el anterior especificador `%u`, obteniendo así bits de la primera o tercera variables pasadas? Es decir, el primer argumento pasado es un `long long` de 8 bytes con todos los bits a 1. Si de ese valor se obtienen 4 bytes para imprimir un valor de tipo `unsigned int` debido al primer especificador `%u`, ¿no empezaría a imprimir el valor del segundo especificador `%llu` a partir del 4 byte del primer argumento `unsigned long long` pasado (con todos los bits a 1) y, por lo tanto, dando un valor distinto de `0`?**

**Si el segundo especificador es para obtener un valor de tipo `unsigned long long` de 8 bytes pero la segunda variable es de tipo `unsigned int` de 4 bytes, ¿no obtendría el valor mostrado algunos bits de las otras dos variables?**

*PD: Los especificadores no corresponden intencionadamente con los tipos de datos de las variables pasadas por argumentos para poder entender el problema.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> creo suponer que por cada especificador indicado se obtiene un valor de la pila del tamaño precisado por el especificador

Crees mal; la explicación la tiene la [convención de llamada a función](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenci%C3%B3n_de_llamada_a_funci%C3%B3n).

A grandes rasgos, la convención de llamada indica en que orden se introducen/extraen los argumentos en la pila, y en que punto se realiza la *limpieza* de esta (antes de retornar de la función, o después de hacerlo), el *alineamiento* de los datos en la pila, ...

Esto forma parte del **ABI** (Application Binary Interface) de cada plataforma; es distinto para cada Sistema Operativo y para cada arquitectura.

Recordemos que C no tiene el concepto de *pila*; eso es de mas bajo nivel que el propio lenguaje; en él, solo se habla de *argumentos* de una función y de su *retorno*.

Puedes echarle un vistazo a [esta tabla](https://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Conventions), donde se indican algunas convenciones de llamada. Para x86_64, se utilizan 6 registros; si hay mas argumentos, se recurre a la pila. Y esta se alinea **en bloques de 16 bytes**; es decir, aunque tu quieras introducir un valor de *solo* 4 *bytes* de tamaño, en realidad el compilador usará 16.

Ahí tienes el motivo: estás *metiendo* y *sacando* datos de 16 *bytes* de tamaño; anchura mas que suficiente para que no se *pisen* los *bits* unos a otros :-)

<sub>Por si a alguien le interesa y quiere ahondar, cito algunas: `stdcall`, `pascal`, `fastcall`, `cdecl`, ...</sub>

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias.